# change tabbar text color,iPhone

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I have created a tabbar programmatically.

Can we change color of title of the tabbar item?
Default is white, and i m trying to make it black.

something like

```
 tabbaritem.text.textcolor=[UIcolor Blackcolor];
```

Thanks

Comment: `[UIcolor Blackcolor]` is not a method of `UIColor` and it is `UIColor` I think you ment `[UIColor blackcolor]`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In iOS5 you use the appearance proxy to change the title color:

For a specific tabbar item:

```
[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                         [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:20.0f], UITextAttributeFont,
                                         [UIColor yellowColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                         [UIColor redColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
                                         [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0.0f, 1.0f)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                         nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Or replace `self.tabBarItem` with `[UITabBarItem appearance]` to change all your tabbar items.
If you want to change them all , I suggest you place the code on appdelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Comment: App dont crash anymore, but the color of text is not changing .any idea

Comment: I've updated the code and tested it in a project that uses the `UITabBarController` and it does work.

Comment: just one quick question: can i move the text upwards/downards also?

Answer (score 2):

Just something else ...

To set your standard appearance in iOS 5:

In your AppDelegate.m do:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:myColor]; //or whatever you want to change
```

Saves you a lot of work.

Comment: you mean [[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:myColor];

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this updated code helps someone:

```
[UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor lightGrayColor] } forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[UITabBarItem.appearance setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                                  NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor] }     forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```