# self.tabBarItem respondsToSelector always returns no

Tags: objective-c, fonts, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem, respondstoselector

I am trying to change the font color on tab bar items. I'm using code from this post:

[change tabbar text color,iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11343894/change-tabbar-text-color-iphone)

My code is as follows:

```
if ([self.tabBarItem respondsToSelector:@selector(setTitleTextAttributes:)]) {
    NSLog(@"yes");
    [self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                             darkGreen, UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                             nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"no");
}
```

respondsToSelector always returns no, and I'm stuck as to how to fix it. This code block is in viewDidLoad, and the class is a subclass of UITabBarController.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you confirmed that self.tabBarItem is non-nil?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method `setTitleTextAttributes:` doesn't exists at all, the correct signature of that method is `setTitleTextAttributes: forState:`

```
if ([self.tabBarItem respondsToSelector:@selector(setTitleTextAttributes: forState:)]) {
    NSLog(@"yes");
    [self.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                             darkGreen, UITextAttributeTextColor,
                                             nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
else {
    NSLog(@"no");
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh how silly of me. I cannot believed I overlooked that! Thank you. I changed it and it returns yes, but doesn't update the text color. Would you know where to go from here?

Comment: try replacing `self.tabBarItem` with `[UITabBarItem appearance]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I replaced it and had no luck. Would it be something in storyboard?

Comment: I have written this code in the viewDidLoad method of my custom class that subclasses UITabBarController. i just tried to put this in my appDelegate with no luck. In my appDelegate (under applicationDidFinishLaunching) I created one of my custom class objects and used the same code, substituting 'self' with the object. Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: I just created a tab bar application using storyboard and put the code `[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttri.....];` in `didFinishLaunching` and it worked. I suggest you to try that and see the effect. Create a new dummy project to test it

Comment: `[[UITabBarItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor yellowColor], UITextAttributeTextColor, nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];`